# UWP In-Process AppService connection only when Host app is running

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, background-task, appservice

My UWP app hosts an AppService that runs in the same process as the app does. To do this I have followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process).

The goal of this AppService is to communicate two running Apps.

This is the code I use to allow incoming AppService connections:

```cs
        private AppServiceConnection AppServiceConnection;
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral AppServiceDeferral;

        protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);

            IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance = args.TaskInstance;
            AppServiceTriggerDetails appService = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
            AppServiceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            taskInstance.Canceled += OnAppServicesCanceled;
            AppServiceConnection = appService.AppServiceConnection;
            AppServiceConnection.RequestReceived += OnAppServiceRequestReceived;
            AppServiceConnection.ServiceClosed += AppServiceConnection_ServiceClosed;
        }
        private async void OnAppServiceRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            AppServiceDeferral messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
            ValueSet response = (await IPC.Controller.ProcessIncomeRequests(args.Request.Message.ToDictionary())).ToValueSet();
            await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(response);
            messageDeferral.Complete();
        }

        private void OnAppServicesCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {
            AppServiceDeferral.Complete();
        }
        private void AppServiceConnection_ServiceClosed(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceClosedEventArgs args)
        {
            AppServiceDeferral.Complete();
        }
```

As mentioned in the following [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406815/13839278), a communication from a 'client' app can be established to the 'host' app even if the 'host' app isn't running.
For my purposes, I would like to deny incoming AppServices connections unless the 'host' app is currently running.

Is there a way I can do this? What property could I check within the `OnBackgroundActivated` method to decide whether to accept the `taskInstance` or not?

**UPDATE:**

Is it right to say that the method `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)` is only fired after a "conventional" start up of the app (user launching the app manually)?

If that's the case, then one solution could be to keep track of a boolean variable `AppIsRunning`:

```cs
private static bool AppIsRunning = false;

protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...    
    AppIsRunning = true;
    ...
}

private AppServiceConnection AppServiceConnection;
private BackgroundTaskDeferral AppServiceDeferral;

protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);

    IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance = args.TaskInstance;
    AppServiceTriggerDetails appService = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
    AppServiceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    taskInstance.Canceled += OnAppServicesCanceled;
    AppServiceConnection = appService.AppServiceConnection;
    AppServiceConnection.RequestReceived += OnAppServiceRequestReceived;
    AppServiceConnection.ServiceClosed += AppServiceConnection_ServiceClosed;
}
private async void OnAppServiceRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    if (AppIsRunning)
    {
        AppServiceDeferral messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
        ValueSet response = (await IPC.Controller.ProcessIncomeRequests(args.Request.Message.ToDictionary())).ToValueSet();
        await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(response);
        messageDeferral.Complete();
    }
}

private void OnAppServicesCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
{
    AppServiceDeferral.Complete();
}
private void AppServiceConnection_ServiceClosed(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceClosedEventArgs args)
{
    AppServiceDeferral.Complete();
}
```

This way the incoming AppService requests wouldn't be handled when the app is not currently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my Update to the question, tracking a boolean variable that changes it's default value when the `OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)` method is called could be used as a workaround for the required purposes. The value of this variable should be checked before accepting an AppService Request, to decide whether it is accepted or not.

Comment: I tested your update and it's a good solution, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to deny incoming AppServices connections unless the
> 'host' app is currently running.

According to the current design, In-Process AppService uses `OnBackgroundActivated` as EntryPoint. When BackgroundActivated is triggered, the AppService is awakened by the client app. Currently, there is no document API that can determine whether the host app is running.

> What property could I check within the OnBackgroundActivated method to
> decide whether to accept the taskInstance or not?

In `OnBackgroundActivated` and `AppServiceRequestReceivedEvent`, there is also no property that can be used to determine whether the host app is running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with a possible solution. Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: @Miguel I think it will be a workaround, you could post it as answer and accept it.